# Marking/labeling node-edge connection points with graphviz

Tags: layout, graphviz, graph-drawing, labeling

With Graphviz, I know I can label edges and vertices. But what if I want to label some of the connections? That is, label some points where a specific edge meets a specific vertex? Is that possible?

**Notes:**

- I don't care about beatuy/visual styles, I'll take something plain and dirty(ish)
- I would very much rather not use "tricks" such as spacing out the vertex label to make some of the text appear next to the connection points and similar approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `taillabel` and `headlabel` edges attributes. For example:

```
digraph G {
        rankdir="LR";
        a->b [taillabel="from"; headlabel="to"]
        b->c [taillabel="from"; headlabel="to"]
}
```

produce:

[image: example]

Comment: Oh, that's just what I needed, great :-) ... is there also some way to "space out" the edge, or better control where the tail and head labels are placed? Also, is there a specific reason you set `rankdir="LR"` or is it just to get the right-to-left effect for your specific example?

Comment: You're welcome. The `rankdir` is just for the example. You can use `minlen` for more long edges

Answer (score 0):

A clear way to label where something is leaving or coming into a node is to use "port"-like constructs inside the source/target nodes. Some ways to achieve this:

subgraph.dot

```
digraph {
  subgraph cluster_house {
    label="House"
    hcw [label="Clean water"]
    hdw [label="Dirty water"]
  }
  subgraph cluster_street {
    label="Street"
    scw [label="Clean water"]
    sdw [label="Dirty water"]
  }
  scw -> hcw
  hdw -> sdw
}
```

[image]

Docs: https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/cluster/

struct.dot

```
digraph structs {
    node [shape=record];
    rankdir=LR
    house [label="<l> House|<cw> Clean water|<dw> Dirty water"];
    street [label="<l> Street|<cw> Clean water|<dw> Dirty water"];
    street:cw -> house:cw;
    house:dw -> street:dw;
}
```

[image]

Docs: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record

I don't know how to make the headers stand out however with this approach: [graphviz: record node with a bold title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171344/graphviz-record-node-with-a-bold-title)

html.dot

```
digraph structs {
    node [shape=plaintext]
    house [label=<
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
  <th><td><b>House</b></td></th>
  <tr><td port="cw">Clean water</td></tr>
  <tr><td port="dw">Dirty water</td></tr>
</table>>];
    street [label=<
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
  <th><td><b>Street</b></td></th>
  <tr><td port="cw">Clean water</td></tr>
  <tr><td port="dw">Dirty water</td></tr>
</table>>];
    street:cw -> house:cw;
    house:dw -> street:dw;
}
```

[image]

Docs: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

Tested on Graphviz 2.42.2, Ubuntu 22.04.